# Cheerio problems on parsing html by selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, selector, cheerio

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');

    request('http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite', function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var temp = $('#tblproxy tbody tr.loading-row')

        console.log(temp.attr('class'))

      }
    });
```

The webpage is at http://www.gatherproxy.com/zh/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite

I want to get this element and its selector is #tblproxy > tbody > tr.loading-row

I tried the same thing in the google console,

```
var s = $('#tblproxy > tbody > tr.loading-row')
undefined
s.attr('class')
"loading-row"
```

But it doesn't work in the context of cheerio, the output for the program is undefined, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the element, `tbody`, that you're trying to query is loaded asynchronously. This is beyond the scope of what the `request` module is capable of. You can use **[phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs)** in simulating a web page in a headless manner and get the html from a web page module. If you want to create more customized web page modules you can refer to the **[`phantomjs documentation`](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html)**.

Fork this **[github repo demo](https://github.com/ryeballar/phantomjs-sample)** .

First, create a webpage module to get the html of a specific page.

**phantom/request.js**

```
'use strict';

var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {

    console.log(page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    }));

    phantom.exit();

});
```

---

Second, create a phantomjs cli wrapper for all web page modules inside the `phantom` directory.

**lib/phantom.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs');
var fs = require('fs');
var binPath = phantomjs.path;
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

var phantomPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    '..',
    'phantom'
);

exports = module.exports = function() {

    var args = slice.call(arguments);
    var callback = args.pop();

    var command = spawn(binPath, args);

    command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        callback(null, data.toString());
    });

    command.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        callback({ message: data.toString() }, null);
    });

};

// create methods base on the ./phantom directory web page modules
fs.readdirSync(phantomPath).reduce(function(context, filename) {

    var index = path.basename(filename, '.js');

    context[index] = function() {
        exports.apply(null, [path.join(phantomPath, filename)].concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };

}, exports);
```

---

Lastly, use the `lib/phantom.js` script's `request` method to get the html page.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var phantom = require('./lib/phantom');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var address = 'http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite';

phantom.request(address, function(err, html) {

    if(err) {
        console.log('error');
        return;
    }

    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var temp = $('#tblproxy tbody tr.loading-row');

    console.log(temp.attr('class'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code source of the page, there is no `tbody` in `#tblproxy`, so remove it from the selector:

```
var temp = $('#tblproxy tr.loading-row');
```

**Update**

Following bublik42's comment, if a `tbody` appears randomly, you can use `find()`:

```
var temp = $('#tblproxy').find('tr.loading-row');
```

Comment: tbody is in the page source code, but it's the only element inside of #tblproxy. Cheerio somehow omits it.

Comment: Weird, I just checked in Iron (Chromium fork), IE11, Firefox and the downloaded html by cheerio, there is no tbody in sight.